# Type Script after compile refers to this of global scope

Tags: typescript

Hey Everyone I'm new in TypeScript.
I'm trying to write some Function, with reference to this of Function and after compilation i'm getting this of Window.
I can't understand why it's doing this.
Thank's for any advice.
Here is the code

**TS**

```
var checkSection  = () => {
$('.section').each((index)=> {
        var $this     = $(this),
            topEdge:number   = $this.offset().top,
            bottomEdge:number = topEdge + $this.height(),
            wScroll:number   = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(topEdge < wScroll && bottomEdge > wScroll) {
            var current:string = $this.data('section');
            console.log('current data attribute ' + current);
            console.log('current index ' + index);
        }
    })
}
```

**JS output**

```
var _this = this;
var checkSection = function () {
    $('.section').each(function (index) {
        var $this = $(_this), 
            topEdge = $this.offset().top, 
            bottomEdge = topEdge + $this.height(),
            wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (topEdge < wScroll && bottomEdge > wScroll) {
            var current = $this.data('section');
            console.log('current data attribute ' + current);
            console.log('current index ' + index);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what the [arrow operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is for - maintaining the context of `this`, so that it is the same as the context in which the function was declared. If you don't want that behavior, don't use `=>`. Use `function`.

Alternatively, don't assume `this` inside a jQuery callback is a reference to the current element. Instead, use the handle to the element which is passed into your `.each` callback:

```
$('.section').each(function (index, element) {
  var $this = $(element)
```

Comment: Thank you for help ! I don't know it, that i can pass second parameter to a callback inside each func after index. VERY USEFULL Thank you. and  that is only difference between function and arrow notation?